# Error al comparar dos fechas utilizando Carbon en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, date, datetime, carbon

tengo el siguiente inconveniente. Actualmente estoy utilizando Carbon para calcular la diferencia entre dos fechas. Una de ellas es la fecha en la que el usuario se registró en mi sitio, alojada en una base de datos mediante DATETIME. La otra es la fecha actual. El resultado se muestra pero el error sucede ya que si la diferencia entre estas dos fechas es muy próxima, el resultado se muestra por default "hace 5 horas". Es decir, detecta automáticamente que la diferencia entre ambas fechas es de 5 horas, cuando en realidad por ejemplo pueden haber transcurrido apenas 1, 2 horas o incluso minutos. No logro solucionarlo. Adjunto el código correspondiente.

**Para arrastrar la información del usuario requerido desde la base de datos**

```
include 'php/conexion_be.php';
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = filter_var($_GET['id'], (FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
    $myuser = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$id' ");
    $use = mysqli_fetch_array($myuser);
}
```

**Calculando la diferencia entre fechas**

```
<?php 
    $fechareg = $use['fecha_reg'];
    require 'php/Carbon/autoload.php';
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Carbon\CarbonInterval;
    use Carbon\CarbonInterface;
    $date = Carbon::parse($fechareg);
    $date->locale('es');
    $now = Carbon::now('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
    $diff = $date->diffForHumans($now, CarbonInterface::DIFF_RELATIVE_TO_NOW);
 ?>
 <li>Registrado desde: <span><?php echo $diff;?></span>
```

**Datos de 'fecha_reg' alojados en la base de datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cómo se muestran las variables (el primer resultado es la fecha actual en UTC-3, el segundo es la fecha de registro traida desde una base de datos también en UTC-3 y el ultimo es el error que me muestra al calcular la diferencia)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Luca, podrías dejar un print de que tienes en la variable `$use['fecha_reg']`

Comment: Ok ya lo agrego!

Comment: Listo! Ya lo añadi. Cada campo corresponde a un usuario distinto

Comment: ¿No te es más fácil comparar en base a TIMESTAMP generados con Carbon? Eso te evitaría el problema que estás teniendo, las diferencias de tiempos son distintas por la forma en la que las estás recuperando

Comment: Necesito que el resultado se exprese de la forma "Hace *x* minutos/horas/días". Entiendo que la forma mas adecuada de lograr eso es utilizando Carbon, como crees que podria solucionarlo utilizando lo que me dices en tu comentario?

Comment: Ya actualicé la pregunta con una imagen de cómo se muestra actualmente cada fecha, con sus respectivas aclaraciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error era completamente mío por omitir una especificación al momento de declarar una variable, ja! Era mas simple de lo que creía. Simplemente debía agregar el timezone a la variable de mi fecha de registro, al igual que lo hacía en mi variable de fecha actual. Adjunto el código que me ayudó a resolverlo.

```
<?php 
$fechareg = $use['fecha_reg'];
require 'php/Carbon/autoload.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonInterval;
use Carbon\CarbonInterface;
$now = Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'));
$date = Carbon::create($fechareg, 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
$date->locale('es');
$diff = $date->diffForHumans($now, CarbonInterface::DIFF_RELATIVE_TO_NOW);
?>
```